# SSL Certificate. HTTPS. Self Signed. Import to Visual studio to protect data transfers

Tags: c#, silverlight, ssl, https, certificate

I have been testing with a self signed certificate in windows 7 IIS (most recent version).

I have configured it to work with my published silverlite project.

the problem is, on my log on screen, i query a service to see if my gateway service is online.

i then recieve a whole bunch of error messages stating "mixed content" and these casue the web browser to freeze up!

I assume this is from the data being transfered in the silerlight app.

How can i use my self signed certificate in visual studio to put HTTPS onto the back end queries so the web browsers are ok with the data transfers between the app and the server?

Please help :)

Answer (score 1):

Mixed content warnings from the browser usually means that the main page is using HTTPS but URL references for child elements on that page (such as URLs for images or script) are HTTP.

When switching a page from running HTTP to HTTPS, *all* URIs loaded in the context of the page (images, script, AJAX content) must use the same URI scheme (HTTPS) or the page is not considered truly secure.

Comment: yes, so i need to associate my self signed certificate to my visual studio project , cause i change the URIS in the program right?
or do i have to add each navigation URL into the something or other?